# Use of "would" to depict uncertain future

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, modal-verbs

Consider the following scenario:

1. A clinical trial that was initiated in Jan 2021 is currently recruiting participants.
2. The estimated enrollment of the trial is 50 participants.
3. It is not always sure that all the participants will be enrolled in a clinical trial – the study can decide to reduce the number of participants during the study.

In that case, if I have to report the trial information in a report, can I use **“the trial would enroll 50 participants”** to depict an uncertain future event? Moreover, will the use of **“the trial is estimated to enroll 50 participants”** depict a higher level of uncertainty than the former?

**Given the option, which one would you prefer to depict a situation with all the uncertainties involved in a setting of technical report writing?**

Comment: I think your 3rd sentence is cumbersome/awkward and could be improved.  Try this: "Not all the participants will necessarily be enrolled in the clinical trial - the number of participants may be reduced during the study."  The main problem I see with your example is the way you have worded it.  A "study" can't make a "decision". It's not a human.

Comment: No, would is not referring to a specific future event. It refers to what the event would look like, **if the trial were run**.

Answer (score 1):

Would is perfectly acceptable/understandable, although it also wouldn't sound strange to use "will".

If you wanted to imply uncertainty, I would not say "the trial is estimated to enroll 50 participants" because they have a concrete goal of getting 50 participants, should the trial be approved. Instead, I would have the qualifier on the trial. **"If authorized, the trial would enroll 50 participants** or **"The trial would seek to enroll 50 participants**

Comment: So "trial would enroll 50 participants" means that the trial is doubtful to take place, but if it does, it'll enroll 50 participants, right?

Comment: Also, using the qualifier "authorized" seem to establish that if the trial gets a get-go, it will enroll 50 participants.

Comment: Both of those statements are correct, although I wouldn't say the first one is necessarily _doubtful_ more that it's just not a certainty to happen. "Doubtful" implies it's unlikely. Depending on the context though, it might be almost certain but not fully authorized. "would" should work in both cases.

Comment: Suppose, I mention that the trial was initiated in January 2021 and is currently in recruiting phase. In that case, would "the trial would enroll 50 participants" mean that the trail is ongoing but uncertain if 50 participants will be enrolled?

Comment: Just want to clarify if "would" can be used to specify uncertain events in the future in the setting of technical writing. It might be potentially ambiguous to a non-native speaker, as it could be construed as reporting a definite, and now unchangeable, future-in-the-past event.

Comment: I would say "would" implies more uncertainty than "will". Since the trial has been authorized and is now seeking participants, I would say "will", but since you still want the uncertainty of not knowing if they'll get 50 participants, I would say "Authorized in Jan 2021, the trial will seek to enroll 50 participants." That's totally unambiguous.

Answer (score -1):

I do not think would is correct here. I suggest the appropriate usage is

> The trial has a target recruitment of 50 participants

it is true that estimated could be used in the right context.

> The sample size determination estimated that 50 participants would be needed to achieve 90% power for a minimally clinically important difference of 1 point on the ...